# Line of thinking for deriving the Lorentz Transformation in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

We're given two inertial frames $S$ and $S'$ moving with relative speed $v$. For simplicity, we’ll start by ignoring the directions y and z which are perpendicular to the direction of motion Both reference frames come with cartesian coordinates $(x, t)$ for S and $(x', t')$ for $S'$. Therefore the most general transformation between them is of the form :
$$
x' = f(x, t ) \\t' = g(x, t)
$$
But we can use the fact that the law of inertia holds and a particle left alone to itself will continue moving with constant velocity. Therefore, a particle moving with a constant speed is mapped as a straight line in the frame $S$. Since both $S$ and $S'$ are inertial frames a straight line in $S$ is mapped to a straight line in $S'$. This restricts the initial transformational form to the following:
$$
x' = ax +bt\\t' = cx + dt
$$ 
Now, we know that $S'$ moves with a speed $v$ relative to $S$. This means that the origin in $S'$ is mapped to a straight line $x=vt$ in $S$.
$$
x' = a(x-vt) \tag{1}
$$
Now, assume $S'$ moves to the left wrt $S$ instead of right with the same constant velocity $v$.
We could just replace the $v$ to a $-v$ in the equation $1$ and we would have:
$$
x' = a(x+vt) (1)
$$
Since the names given to the coordinate axes are just dummy names, we can interchange them ($S' <-> S$) and the respective symbols of position and time corresponding to them. This gives us: 
$$
x = a(x' + vt') (2)
$$
Note what this swapping of coordinates does physically. Now, we have the same situation as earlier but this switching of velocity direction and the frames now signifies that we're looking at the same situation as before but w.r.t $S'$ ($S$ moving left with velocity $v$ w.r.t $S'$).

Now, since light travels with the same speed in both the reference frames, we have:

$$
x=ct(3)\\x'=ct'(4)
$$
Substituting the trajectories (3) and (4) into (1) and (2) and solving, we get:
$$
a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\\
t' = a(t-\frac{v}{c^2}x)
$$

Is my line of thinking correct or have I made any errors (like two wrongs making a right sort of a situation)? I am convinced with this but the other sources do not seem to convince me. For example, Prof. Shankar argues that the $\gamma$ factor must be the same for both $S$ and $S'$ because of isotropy. If one reference frame jacks up the length measured by $\gamma$, there is no reason for the other frame to not. Now this explanation, I think, is somewhat synonymous with what I have done. But still, that isn't convincing enough to me. So it would be great if somebody could help me out here. Thanks.